# Calling function onClick of label that is bound to input type radio using 'for' attribute in mobile devices

Tags: jquery

I want to call a function onclick of label associated with input radio. This works fine on desktop machines but not on mobile devices. I am using jquery swipe for mobile devices.
I have input buttons and labels bound to that.
eg.

```
<input type="radio" id="1" />
<label for="1">1</label>
```

For mobile devices :
I am unbinding click from radio button and attaching swipe to it.

```
$("#1").unbind("click");

$("#1").swipe({
   click : function () {
   }
});
```

This works fine. But when I click on label this function is not called. Do I need to add some specific event on label for mobile mode?

Answer (score 5):

label does not have id `1` so your selector is wrong, you need to bind the handlers to label with `for` attribute value 1

```
$("#1").unbind("click");

$("label[for=1]").on('swipe', function(){

});
```

Comment: Id 1 is for input radio button. I am unbinding event from that. I have class for the set of labels, and I had done same thing but using class and it didnt work.

Comment: This, and on top of that, ID's generally shouldn't start with an integer.

Comment: Id 1 is just for example.

Comment: @sonam are you using jQuery mobile?

Answer (score 2):

let your `onclick` in label `return false;` to prevent default behaviour!

```
 <label for="1" onclick="myFunction(); return false;">1</label>
```